# Operations on the columns with the same names in two data set in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a =c(1), b=c(4), c=c(1))

df2 <- data.frame (b =c(4), c=c(1), a=c(4))
```

I wish to do operations on the columns with the same name: for example for column `a`, I want to do this operation (a(in df1) - a (in df2)) / a (in df1)

that is `(1-4) /1 = -3`

So my ideal output will be:

```
 a b c
-3 0 0
```

I'll try to write a function as follows but not sure how to proceed. Any tip is really appreciated.

```
my_func <- function(x,y) {
  for (i in names(x)) 
    if ((i %in% names(y))) {
      df3 [i,] <- (x[i,] - y[i,]) / x[i,]
    }
}
```

**Update**

Ideally, it would be great if I can consider the missing columns. For example, if there is a missing column in df2, I wish to have `0` and if the missing column is in df2 the output can be anything like"no value"

Comment: why is b and c 0?

Comment: because `b` in both data set is 4 so the result is (4-4) / 4 and for `c` is (1-1) / 1. Sorry perhaps it wasn't the best example that I could provide

Comment: is the operation common across columns?

Comment: currently, I have two datasets that each of them has only one row. So, I'm not worried about the columns

Comment: are the dataframe jumbled? also could there be a possibility that the df may not have a particular column?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: can there be a possibility of a column missing?

Comment: yes @Hardikgupta this one is also possible

Comment: in case of missing column, how would your output be like, can you please update that in the question

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, I updated the question

Comment: it really looks like your desired data type is `matrix` and not `data.frame`. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Someone might want to expand on it for missing data, but this is a good case for `Map/mapply` - `mapply(function(n,x,y) (x[,n]-y[,n])/x[,n], c("a","b","c"), list(df1), list(df2))` for instance.

Comment: When you get an answer, it is very bad to delete the question.  Somebody made an effort to answer your answer.  In the future when you post a question, people will be hesitant to answer if it is going to be deleted

Comment: Sorry, it was a stupid mistake and I believe keeping the question didn't add any value to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
res <- NULL
for (str in colnames(df1))
  res <- c(res, (df1[str] - df2[str]) / df1[str] )

res
#$a
#[1] -3

#$b
#[1] 0

#$c
#[1] 0
```

If you wish make it a numeric

```
out <- as.numeric(res)
names(out) <- names(res)
out
# a  b  c 
#-3  0  0
```

If the columns do not match...

```
col_nam1 <- colnames(df1)
col_nam2 <- colnames(df2)
all_col_names <- unique(c(col_nam1, col_nam2))
res <- NULL
for (str in all_col_names)
  if ((str %in% col_nam1) && (str %in%col_nam2))
    res <- c(res, (df1[str] - df2[str]) / df1[str])
```

Inspired from @Hardik gupta, doing it without loops:

```
common_names <- sort(intersect(col_nam2, col_nam1))
(df1[, common_names] - df2[, common_names]) / df1[, common_names]
```

Zeros if `df1` has column that `df2` doesn't

```
df1 <- data.frame(a =c(1), b=c(4), c=c(1), f = 4)
df2 <- data.frame (b =c(4), c=c(1), a=c(4), g = 5)

col_nam1 <- colnames(df1)
col_nam2 <- colnames(df2)

common_names <- intersect(col_nam2, col_nam1)
col_names <- sort(unique(col_nam1, common_names))
res <- numeric(length(col_names))
names(res) <- col_names

res[common_names] <- (df1[, common_names] - df2[, common_names]) / 
                                       df1[, common_names]
out <- as.numeric(res)
names(out) <- names(res)
out
 a  b  c  f 
-3  0  0  0
```

Comment: solution will fail if there is any column missing from df1 and df2

Comment: True. I think I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Taking help from @Headpoint answers, you can directly do this (no need of loops)

```
df1 <- data.frame(a =c(1), b=c(4), c=c(1))
df1 <- df1[, order(names(df1))]

df2 <- data.frame (b =c(4), c=c(1), a=c(4))
df2 <- df2[, order(names(df2))]

all_col_names <- unique(colnames(df1),  colnames(df2))

df1[, all_col_names] - df2[, all_col_names]

   a b c
1 -3 0 0
```